# Linear layout clickable error

Tags: android-layout

In my Andoid app. I have a clickable linear layout that I've generated programmaticly, and I want it to turn green when it is pressed to indicate that it is clickable, like a button would. How would I go about doing this?

---

This is my code i implemented in my Header layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/back_lay"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/ib_back_music"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_btn_sel"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Showing your code and what you did would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private LinearLayout lLinearLayout;

//OnCreate
lLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_lay);
lLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new 
{
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           lLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

});
```

Comment: I have been posted my code i implemented in my Header layout.

Comment: Check out the solution and let me know

Comment: Have you increased the layout sizes to see if it works
layout_width = "match_parent"
layout_heigth = "match_parent"
NO MATTER which version you are running this should work